# Is there a way to refer to the current project name in Talend?

Tags: talend

I am setting up a Talend project that I am going to be using as a basis for many future projects.  I would like to send out a generic email if the job runs successfully or if it fails.  I would like to dynamically include the name of the project in the email subject and message.  Is there a way to dynamically pull the project name from a Talend project?  If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "Message" field you can use the projectName variable. So for example:

```
projectName + " finished."
```

You can also hit ctrl+space while in the message text area and it'll show you all available variables and functions.

Comment: Thanks!  That ctrl+space feature is very helpful.  I thought there was a way to do that, but wasn't sure how.  I think global.projectname is the variable I was looking for.